# Why does this closure's lifetime change based on seemingly unrelated types?

Tags: rust

With the code

```
fn foo<'a, 'b>(
    state: &'b mut i32,
) -> impl FnMut(&'a str) -> &'static str + 'b {
    |s| "hi"
}
```

I get an error

```
error[E0482]: lifetime of return value does not outlive the function call
112 | ) -> impl FnMut(&'a str) -> &'static str + 'b {
    |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: the return value is only valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the function body at 110:9
110 | fn foo1<'a, 'b>(
    |         ^^
```

But somehow the code

```
fn foo2<'a, 'b>(
    state: &'b mut Option<&'a i32>,
) -> impl FnMut(&'a str) -> &'static str + 'b {
    |s| "hi"
}
```

compiles without errors. Why does the type of `state` change the lifetime of the closure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With type `&'b mut Option<&'a i32>`, Rust infers the lifetime bound `'a: 'b` (`'a` outlives `'b`). This bound is required for the function signature to be well-formed. You can add this bound explicitly to avoid the error:

```
fn foo<'a, 'b>(
    state: &'b mut i32,
) -> impl FnMut(&'a str) -> &'static str + 'b
where
    'a: 'b,
{
    |s| "hi"
}
```

However, if no parameter uses `'a`, then `'a` should be a higher-rank trait bound instead:

```
fn foo<'b>(
    state: &'b mut i32,
) -> impl for<'a> FnMut(&'a str) -> &'static str + 'b {
    |s| "hi"
}
```

The `Fn` family of traits are special in that they allow you to omit the lifetime entirely (following the same elision rules as `fn` signatures), so this is equivalent:

```
fn foo<'b>(
    state: &'b mut i32,
) -> impl FnMut(&str) -> &'static str + 'b {
    |s| "hi"
}
```

Comment: So what does the error mean then? Is the closure type not valid since it requires an argument with a lifetime that might have expired by the time it gets called? I thought Rust could infer `'a` at `foo`'s callsite.

Comment: @Dan Function signatures are required to be fully described. I mean no guessing should be possible when looking at the sole signature. I suppose you are just confused why removing `'a` from input lifetimes causes rustc to complain. In the example `'a` lifetime appears only in the output types and has no connection to input lifetimes so it becomes _unbounded_, which rustc prohibits.